# Loading fonts in symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

Don't know how to load ttf font types on css files for twig in symfony2 app. Any suggestions? The ttf are inside a folder in resources. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Load font in twig? You probably want to have some custom fonts in you CSS file that defines styling of the twig.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: GiveItSomeName;
    src: url(locationToYourFont.ttf);
    // you can add stuff like font-style, or font-weight...
}
```

And then later in your CSS file, use it like there was a font named GiveItSomeName in those classes you wish, like this

```
.someClass {
    font-family: GiveItSomeName;
}
```